# how to compute the GPU memory needed when training

Tags: tensorflow, memory, gpu, nvidia, conv-neural-network

guys!I want to compute the GPU memory needed when training,the model  configuration is below and on the right is my calculation process.But when I run the program, the GPU memory used 1701M.This is very different from my calculation.
[model configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwHV.png)

[GPU memory used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvhJA.png)

Comment: Is it possible you might have missed the memory used for loading dataset in memory. ie. memory used by input vectors

Comment: It may be not,I use two different dataset.One(66M) is a subset of the other(1.78G). But the GPU memory used is the same.

Comment: It may also be possible that tensor flow is occupying all available GPU on your system irrespective of your model.

Comment: My GPU memory is 11G, I used function 'tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)' to set the memory self-growth, I am not clear if this has an impact.